# Image resources disappearing from react-native app

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, navigation

I'm having a strange problem that I cant quite figure out the reason for. I have an app created in react-native and I'm using react-native-navigation to handle the navigation. The problem is that the images I add to buttons, tabs, etc disappear after I unplug my device from the computer.

To make it clear; all my buttons have icons while I'm connected to the computer and use the app, but once I disconnect from the computer and open the app every icon disappears.

Here is how I load the images

```
 Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
tabs: [
  {
    label: 'One',
    screen: 'Screen1',
    icon: require('./images/icon1.png'),
    selectedIcon: require('./images/icon1_selected.png'),
    title: 'Screen One'
  },
  {
    label: 'Two',
    screen: 'Screen2',
    icon: require('./images/icon2.png'),
    selectedIcon: require('./images/icon2_selected.png'),
    title: 'Screen Two'
  }
]
});
```

any ideas or help on this issue?

Comment: How were you running the app on the device? react-native run-x? Another method? And when you say unplug, do you mean that you unplug and continue using the app as is? Or did you deploy the app? You need to add more detail since you haven't posted any errors to help identify the issue.

Comment: Well there aren't any errors really. I run the app through react-native run-android. What I mean is I unplug my phone from the PC and restart the app on my phone, and the images are all gone. I have not deployed the app, simply installed through run-android.

Comment: I've never looked into the specifics of `run-android` but my guess would be that it's possible that it doesn't bundle all assets by default since it's a development build. If you install it via a release build (`--variant=release`) instead, does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: You were absolutely right, changing to a release solved the issue!

Comment: Glad I could help. Also learned something new today.

Comment: In addition to Michael Cheng's (correct) answer, you [should probably](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require) have your `require` statements at the top level, not inline. Otherwise it may be that the resources aren't loaded until that statement is executed, after you unplug the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure guesswork in the comments, but turned out that `react-native run-android` doesn't automatically bundle your assets as it's a development build. If you need to test the build while completely disconnected from your computer, you can install using a release build using `--variant=release` as that will always bundle your assets with the apk.

Comment: Just to add that `--variant=release` only works after setting up signing [as described here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)