# React Native Android APK size of release vs debug build

Tags: react-native

I've inherited an existing react-native project that is under development and has not yet been released. This is my first time working with react-native, but not react, java, or javascript.

I'm finding that when I build a release version, the size of the APK is larger than the debug version:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 tauren  staff  41105543 Jun 27 12:17 app-debug.apk
-rw-r--r--  1 tauren  staff  55726694 Jun 27 12:55 app-release.apk
```

Is the larger size because all of the javascript is included in the release apk while the debug apk doesn't include any javascript due to it being delivered instead by the react packager?

Or is this not typical and I should be looking for something wrong with the project configuration?

Comment: Could it be that some assets are not included in the debug version? There was [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705685/image-resources-disappearing-from-react-native-app/44781982#44781982) where this seemed to point to that being the case with debug vs release apk. However, I cannot find any documentation on the behavior of each.